# Unity - TextMeshPro Assembly Reference not being recognized

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use TextMeshPro plugin which requires the TextMeshPro library.

The problem is, despite the fact that the library includes this reference, it's still not recognized.

Using the old TMPro library does not help as I need to create an object with the type TextMeshPro.

Any idea why and how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: isn't it `TMPro` instead of `Unity.TextMeshPro`?

Comment: I tried it, but it does not allow me to create an object of type TextMeshPro, I think TMPro relates to an older version of the plugin.

Comment: If you don't find your answer, un-accept the accepted one then edit your current one. Also comment on answers and let the poster know that it didn't work. Finally, don't ignore comments under your question. Don't create new question if you don't get a working answer.

Comment: Yes, I got it, thanks! I did just that.

Answer (score 2):

What you should use as namespace is `using TMPro;` 
Sample Usage.

```
TextMeshPro myText;
myText=GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
//Access the properties
//Example
MyText.text="Sample Text";
```

Comment: I tried it, but it does not allow me to create an object of type TextMeshPro, I think TMPro relates to an older version of the plugin.

Comment: Can you please show what you are trying to do? The namespace has not changed.

Comment: I'm trying to create a type TextMeshPro object but Visual Studio does not recognize the type, it says that an Assembly Reference is missing.

Comment: Inclugin "using TMPro;"  does not solve the problem, the type TextMeshPro is not recognized...

Comment: Please consider re-importing the TeztMeshPro package and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I tried that once and updated to the latest version but still the same...

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i did it:

```
using TMPro;

//getting reference via inspector
public TextMeshProUGUI tmpro;
tmpro.text = "Your Text";
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue this way (probably works with other namespace errors as well)

1. In Unity (not VS)
   Edit > Preferences > External Tools > [select Visual Studio]
2. Regenerate Project Files
3. Close VS then re-open

worked for me